# Android Marketplace Data File Location

Tags: android, path, google-play, apk

I'm developing an app in Unity3D and the file size exceeds the 30mb limitations for some devices. For this reason i will be splitting up the main application apk and have at least one data file with all the assets. Only the main application will be downloaded from the marketplace which will act as an installer.
What i'd like to do is upload the extra data file(s) to the marketplace as well (Android allows 2 extra 2gb data files), and then access these files from the installer to download to the SD card and install.
The installer itself is taken care of from another member of the community, what i'd like to figure out is if it is possible to determine to location of these data files on the marketplace before uploading the installer? As i would need to specify the locations within the installer binary.

I'm aware that the link to your app on the marketplace can be found through:

```
market://details?id=com.example.your.package
```

But would the data file locations work similarly? For instance:

```
market://details?id=com.example.your.package.datafile1
market://details?id=com.example.your.package.datafile2
```

Thanks!

Comment: upload them first and see, but it should be the 2 you listed last.

Comment: I just did a test on the marketplace, i uploaded two different apk's that all seems to work fine. So you're telling me that my assumption would be correct? Just reference it like above with the correct package name?

Comment: Should be, when I add my AdMob, I just use that formula to get my account code, then upload the app to the market.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for that Bill. I'll try and confirm once i complete the app and upload.

Comment: I've been thinking and experimenting with this more and more, and the more i look at it, the more i think that this isn't possible. It shouldn't be possible in the first place, because it if was this easy to retrieve a link to an uploaded APK, then you can simply use a script to download any app/game you want.
Unless there is a specific are to upload additional data files i dont think this can be done at all...

Comment: ok, i just surfed to one of my apps on the market, and the url in the address was different than the one i used for admob, so i huess you can't. the url was https://market.android.com/details?id=com.brggames.skycolladfree#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLmJyZ2dhbWVzLnNreWNvbGxhZGZyZWUiXQ..