# Android Marketplace additional data files

Tags: android, google-play

I'm just wondering if anyone has had experience with uploading apps or games larger than the 50mb limit. Our app does not exceed this limit, however it exceeds the cache limitations of a few different devices we'd like to target.
We've opted for an installer approach splitting the APK into two, an installer, and then a data APK which will be downloaded when installed.

Does anyone know where or how you upload additional APK's to be used as data files?
From my understanding you can upload multiple APK's already, which will be filtered based on devices etc. But can it be used in a similar way to host data files to be downloaded from the actual app?

It was announced in the I/O 2011 that this will be supported by 2011 June, so i'm assuming it can be done already.
http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/05/11/io-2011-google-increases-app-size-limit-to-4gb-tweaks-the-return-policy/

I've gathered that i'd be able to retrieve the app from the market like this:
    'market://details?id=com.example.your.package.datafile1'
[Android Marketplace Data File Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934802/android-marketplace-data-file-location)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the multiple APK system that was announced at I/O in 2011 is for creating device-specific APKs and not for delivering an additional data-file APKs.  One way to get around this restriction is to host the additional data files (such as movies, music, or images) on a server and then have the app make a request to your server for the data when the user runs it for the first time. If you go with the server approach, you'll probably also want to provide a progress bar.

Comment: Yeah, like i said we do have an installer ready which downloads additional data from a server which will show progress and wont allow the app to launch before it has finished downloading.
The announcement didn't really seem to imply that they are supporting multiple APK's for device specific APK's. "the same 50MB initial download app limit, except with the addition of up to 2 2GB data files, hosted and managed by the Market itself."